# Stacked Bar Plot for Temperature vs Home Runs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make some changes to my plot, but am having difficulty doing so.

(1) I would like warm, avg, and cold to be filled in as the colors red, yellow, and blue, respectively.

(2) I am trying to make the y-axis read "Count" and have it be horizontally written.

(3) In the legend, I would like the title to be Temperatures, rather than variable

Any help making these changes would be much appreciated along with other suggestions to make the plot look nicer.

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
      'Statistic  Warm Avg Cold
      Homers(Away) 1.151 1.028 .841
      Homers(Home) 1.202 1.058 .949'), header = TRUE)

    library(ggplot2)
    library(reshape2)

    df <- melt(df, id = 'Statistic')
    ggplot(
      data = df,
      aes(
        y = value, 
        x = Statistic, 
        group = variable, 
        shape = variable, 
        fill = variable
      )
    ) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: You should only stack the bars (_i.e._ fill a single bar with 3 colours) if it makes sense to express the values as proportions of a total. I don't think that is the case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right lines by trying to reshape the data into long format. My preference is to use `gather` from the `tidyr` package for that. You can also create the variable names Temperatures and Count in the gather step.

The next step is to turn the 3 classes of temperature into a factor, ordered from cold, through average, to warm.

Now you can plot. You want `position = "dodge"` to get the bars side by side, since it makes no sense to stack the values in a single bar. Fill colours you specify using `scale_fill_manual`.

You rotate the y-axis title by manipulating `axis.title.y`.

So putting all of that together (plus a black/white theme):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
gather(Temperatures, Count, -Statistic) %>% 
mutate(Temperatures = factor(Temperatures, c("Cold", "Avg", "Warm"))) %>%
ggplot(aes(Statistic, Count)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = Temperatures), position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "yellow", "red")) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
```

Result:
[image]
I'd question whether `Count` is a sensible variable name in this case.

Comment: agree with the dodged bars :)

Comment: I like the way that looks as well!

Comment: I'm getting errors saying no package called 'dplyr' and no function "%>%"

Comment: `install.packages("dplyr", "tidyr")` if you don't have them.

Comment: Do the axis labels have to be one word? You're right, count isn't what the y axis should be.

Comment: Multiple words is fine but you may run into issues if the label is horizontal and too long.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. To map specific colors to specific factor levels you can use **scale_fill_manual** and create your own scale:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("Warm"="red", "Avg"="yellow", "Cold"="blue")) +
```

Changing the y axis legend is also easy in ggplot:

```
ylab("Count") +
```

And to change the legend title you can use:

```
labs(fill='TEMPERATURE') +
```

Giving us:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = value, x = Statistic, group= variable, fill = variable)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("Warm"="red", "Avg"="yellow", "Cold"="blue")) +
labs(fill='TEMPERATURE') +
ylab("Count") +
xlab("") +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]